# QVariant.value<T>() Causing Problems

Tags: c++, qt, qvariant

So I have a custom class Foo which has been registered as a metatype using the `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Foo)` macro at the end of the class definition.

I can set items within a list, check to see if canConvert, but when I try to actually make an item of type Foo things fail at compile time.

Using QVariant passed in from a `QModelIndex &index`:

```
Foo item(index.data(Qt::DisplayRole).value<Foo>())
```

fails with the following error(s):

```
no matching function for call to 'namespace::Foo::Foo(namespace::Foo)'
In instantiation of 'T qvariant_cast(const Foo&) [with T = namesapce::Foo]':
required from 'T QVariant::value() const [with T = namespace::Foo]'
no matching function for call to 'namespace::Foo::Foo(const namespace::Foo &)'
no matching function for call to 'namespace::Foo::Foo(const namespace::Foo&)'    
no matching function for call to 'namespace::Foo::Foo(const namespace::Foo)'
In member function 'T QVariant::value() const [with T = namespace::Foo]'
```

all from file qvariant.h

What am I doing wrong here?
My class has the following constructors:

```
Foo::Foo(const Foo &)
Foo::Foo()
```

The header is as follows:

```
namespace a {
namespace b {
class Foo {
    explicit Foo();
    explicit Foo(const Foo &a);
    ...
};
} // b
} // a
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(a::b::Foo)
```

Comment: show your header, where you placed Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Foo)

Comment: It was originally a subclass of QVariant, but that didn't work either.

Comment: It might be the use of `explicit` on those constructors that's causing the problem.  Also, just to make sure, did you call `qRegisterMetaType<Foo>():`?

Comment: Removing the `explicit` keyword caused it to work correctly. Any idea why that was happening? I want to toss you the answer credit, but I can't do that on comments.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-in-c-mean I'd suppose an implicit conversion is being made?

Answer (score 0):

As Dan Milburn suggested, removing the `explicit` keywords solved the problem. It appears an implicit conversion was occurring in the value call, therefore having only explicit constructors prevented this.